# Converting an integer to to ascii values C++

Tags: c++, string, casting, ascii

I am attempting to turn a number into letters using ascii, at the moment I can do it one letter at a time:

EDIT: The output of an RSA encryption that I've been working on is currently in the form of an integer, I'm trying to work out how to convert it to the word/sentence which was the original input. I've nearly finished but I'm completely stuck at the last "hurdle". I'm adding context due to a comment asking why I would want to do this (or words to that effect).

EDIT: If during the encryption process I used the ASCII value - 87, all letters would be 2 digits long, eliminating the problem of some ASCII characters being 3 letters and some being 2, does this make the problem more approachable? (it limits me to only letter but that's fine for its purpose)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

char returnChar(int x)
{
    return (char) x;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << returnChar (119);
}
```

This converts 32 --> w.

How could I adapt this function to allow me to change "3232" --> "ww" or any other integer to ascii characters, e.g. "32242713" --> "word".

EDIT: I think using some kind of mod function to split it into chunks of two numbers which could then be converted to characters might work?

*How do I overcome the problem of some ascii characters having 2 digits and some having 3 digits?* **I think this problem has been solved as described in the second edit**

**If you can see that I've approached this in entirely the wrong way, could you suggest a viable alternative approach for me to try please?**

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the outer problem that you expect this to solve? The answer to "How do I overcome the problem of some ascii characters having 2 digits and some having 3 digits?" is by never, ever doing anything remotely like this.

Comment: If you want to convert a string of digits represented as a string with no delimiters, that will not work because there is ambiguity in interpretation.

Comment: Maybe if you put commas between the data values, or if you store the data in an array, you could solve your 2 or 3 character problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have almost finished the decryption section of my RSA project that I've been working on, all that's left to do is convert the integer that I get at the end to the characters that were in the original input.

Comment: Ahh, so what you need is a sane way to convert strings to integers. Perhaps you could pad each character to three digits, so 102,31,41,123 would be "102,031,041,123"? (For the record, that's not even remotely close to the way RSA is ever used in reality.)

Comment: @David Scwartz I'm just trying to get into programming and was definitely over-ambitious attempting RSA,I realise now that I've gone about this the wrong way but even though it's nothing comparable to industry standard (or even industry method, oops) I really want to finish it!

Comment: @David Scwartz I've managed to convert the characters to an integer during the encryption process, I just cant convert the final integer in the decryption process back into characters.

Comment: What good is an encryption scheme that makes decryption impossible?

Comment: The decryption isn't impossible. I can convert "a" into a number and then apply C = M ^ e (mod N). this produces a number, which can be passed on. This number is then deciphered C ^ d (mod N) and results in a number, which using the code above I can convert back to the original letter. When I use a word, I have combined the letters so that "10", "11" would become "1011" and I can get back this number at the end, I just need to convert this number to the original letters, if that makes sense?

Comment: "When I use a word, I have combined the letters so that "10", "11" would become "1011" and I can get back this number at the end", yes, that's the part of the encryption that makes decryption impossible.  Is that 1,011 or is it 10,11 or is it 101,1 or is it 1011?

Comment: @Mooing Duck If I minus 87 from all of the ASCII values before the combination process (which I have now done) it means that all of the letters are now expressed as a 2 digit number. I think I've just solved the problem you've brought up? Now that we know that each letter is ALWAYS represented by a 2 digit number surely there must be a way of "chunking" it 2 digits at a time?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not possible. You have a few alternatives:

1. Change the int to a string and put white spaces/other characters inside the string:

   `std::string test = "119 119";`
2. Convert the total value to binary, and parse byte by byte:

   `unsigned int test = 30583; // 119*256+119
   char a = (test>>8)&0xff;
   char b = test&0xff;`
3. Pass the data in a vector and convert one element at a time:

   `std::vector<char> returnChar(const std::vector<int> &data){
       std::vector<char> output;
       for(unsigned int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
          output.push_back(char(data[i]));
       return output;
   }`

I would probably stick with the second method, since - a wild guess here - it shouldn't change much things inside where you actually generate the numbers.

Comment: The integer is going to be a different size and composed of different numbers each time, so I don't think that 1 is an option and please could you expand on 2? I don't think I understand what you mean? Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say "parse byte by byte"?

Comment: There are special binary operators in C++. An integer is (usually) 4 bytes long. You can get the particular bytes of an int by using those operators. The example I gave parses an int into two characters. If you want to store 4 values inside the int, do:
`char a,b,c,d; unsigned int test = (a<<24)+(b<<16)+(c<<8)+d` and retrieve them like in the example (doing `>>` by 0,8,16 and 24)

Comment: @MichaelRad This should help you understand: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: Thanks, but I just can't see how I can use this? Sorry if I'm being frustratingly stupid and I really appreciate the help (even if I don't understand it).

Comment: @MichaelRad my comment shows the usage. I don't really understand what else you need to know. There's an example for writing chars into an int, and for reading them. Do you need anything else? I simply don't know what and how could I expand for you to understand it better, sorry mate.